How does cpu interact with hard drive?
If cpu can't directly access hard drive,then how does a cpu communicate with hard drive to load data into ram?
Let's say a page fault occurs, how does cpu perform the transfer of data from the hard drive to ram if it can't directly access or address it? Am I being wrong? What am I missing?
What is the case when there is DMA and no DMA?
Also as ssd are also integrated circuits,why are they slower than ram?
Please shed some light on these topics.Links to good resources are also welcomed.

@SolomonSlow sory i must have framed my question better, I'm asking how cpu interacts with hard disk, I understand that os is the one that supply that info but how cpu is able to address it if it can't acces the hard disk directly.

@SolomonSlow I have now edited my question.

OK, Comment withdrawn. FWIW, I will not attempt to answer your question. I let go of my hope of knowing everything about how computers work sometime in the 1990s. Anyway, I asked google just now, "How does DMA work?" and it gave me this link (among others): https://www.spiceworks.com/tech/hardware/articles/direct-memory-access/ Three thousand and some words. Probably too long for this forum, and probably comes nowhere near to answering your question. But, maybe it could give you some ideas for questions that would be more focused—easier for an expert to know where to begin with an answer.

@SolomonSlow I can't thank you enough! I'll jump into it right now. I too have been searching for the answer, I have also asked about it on reddit. I'll update when i get the answer.

This question is far too broad to get into the details. It will have to suffice to say that while the CPU cannot directly address an arbitrary byte of data on a hard drive, there is a way to transfer data by blocks between RAM and the drive. This involves layers of software already loaded into RAM (part of the operating system).
How did that software get there? That's called the bootstrapping process, in which a small piece of code in some sort of nonvolatile memory that the CPU can access directly when it first powers up knows just enough to read a file from the drive, possibly in a very basic way, and then that file contains additional code with more sophisticated capabilities that reads in the remaining parts of the OS.

Thank you for your response. Yea my question is broad,sory for that. Could you guide me with some resources which goes into the details? I will follow from there.

Think about how you would implement it. The CPU knows that the memory with logical address X is needed. Where would this be on the hard drive? What would you need to figure it out?
